# Automatic word spacing for long chords writing

Tags: spacing

I currently making a songbook and thus I want to display chords above lyrics. I have found several packages but I want to improve my TeXing skills so I wrote everything from scratch.

Until now, everything works fine apart from one thing: some chords are too long and overlaps with the next one.

I have some way to do it, by explaining each time what text correspond to each chord (see the second part of the minimal example) but it would mean rewriting all song I already have.
So I wanted to know if there was a way to automatically add space when needed, without having to specify which text correspond to which chord!

Here is a minimal example (the whole code is much longer but I don't think it's needed here):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\ch#1{%
  \leavevmode\hbox to 0pt{\vbox{\hbox{\strut\tt#1}\kern.25cm}\hss}%
}

\begin{document}
  \parskip.15cm

  \ch{A}Lorem ipsum \ch{B}dolor sit amet, \ch{C}consectetuer \ch{D}adipiscing elit.

  \ch{A}Ut purus elit, vesti\ch{B}bulum \ch{C}ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, \ch{D}felis.

  \ch{A}Curabi\ch{B7sus4}tur \ch{C}dictum \ch{D7sus4}gravi\ch{E}da mauris.

  \bigskip
  \textit{I would want to have something that look like this:}\par
  \def\foo#1#2{%
    \leavevmode\vbox{\hbox{\strut\tt#1 }\hbox{#2}}%
  }
  \foo{A}{Curabi}\foo{B7sus4}{tur} \foo{C}{dictum}  \foo{D7sus4}{gravi}\foo{E}{da mauris}.

\end{document}
```

which gives
[image: results]

Note: I know that this might not be possible on justified multi-line paragraph, but we only have flushed/centered paragraph here (or even single lines), so the space between words should be fixed (I guess?).

Comment: You could programmatically build a `tabular` for each verse with `l`-type columns and no space between them (`@{}` in `tabular` header). Important is to decide on a convenient input syntax that is easy to parse, yet flexible enough. Maybe something like this? `\begin{myverse}
  {A}{Curabi}, {B7sus4}{tur }, {C}{dictum }, {D7sus4}{gravi}, {E}{da mauris.}
\end{myverse}`. You could possibly use one such environment for the whole, separating verses with ``\\``, but this might make it more difficult to have explicit line breaks within verses later (unless you decide to use a different separator).

Comment: `tabular` is a very good place to start. Put each phrase/chord pair into its own `tabular`: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\begin{document}
\stackon{Curabi}{A}%no space
\stackon{tur}{B7sus4} %<--space
\stackon{Dictum}{C}
\stackon{gravi}{D7sus4}
\stackon{da mauris.}{E}
\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{l}A\\Curabi\\\end{tabular}\kern-1.2em
\begin{tabular}{l}B7sus4\\tur\\\end{tabular}%
\begin{tabular}{l}C\\Dictum\\\end{tabular}%
\begin{tabular}{l}D7sus4\\gravi\\\end{tabular}%
\begin{tabular}{l}E\\da mauris.\\\end{tabular}%
\end{document}`

Comment: Hmm, those solution doesn't really suit me as I would have to rewrite every song I already have... This wasn't clear so I will edit my question, sorry!

Comment: why don't you use the form you use with `\foo` with two arguments that works? It would be only a trivial edit in an editor to change `\ch{[^{}]*}[a-zA-Z]*` to the two argument form `\foo{...}{..}`

Comment: You're right! This is probably the easier solution and I might end up doing it! (I hadn't thought about regexp, thanks for the reminder!) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest using a package like `leadsheets`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{leadsheets}
\setleadsheets{
  align-chords=l ,
  chords/format=\ttfamily
}

\begin{document}

\begin{song}{title=Lorem Ipsum}
\begin{verse}
  ^{A}Lorem ipsum ^{B}dolor sit amet, ^{C}consectetuer ^{D}adipiscing elit. \\
  ^{A}Ut purus elit, vesti^{B}bulum ^{C}ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae,
  ^{D}felis. \\
  ^*{A}Curabi ^{B7sus4}tur ^{C}dictum ^{D7sus4}gravi ^{E}da mauris.  
\end{verse}
\end{song}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Inside the `song` environment chords are placed with the shortcut `^`: `^{chord}word`.

For two chords over one word you'd need to split the word `^*{A}Curabi ^{B7sus4}tur` and let the starred version `^*{chord}word` gobble the following blank.

Comment: It seems to do exactly what I wanted! I'm going to look at the sources of the package, as I'm curious to know how it's done! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is also a simple package called `musixguit` to create chords with the guitar...Here I add a MWE with the my preferite singer:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{musixguit}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Gloria - Umberto Tozzi -}
\begin{song}
\emph{--1979--}
Great Umberto \dSmiley\dSmiley.
  
\chord{SI}Gloria, manchi tu nell'\chord{MI}aria

\chord{SI}manchi ad una mano che lavora \chord{MI}piano

\textit{with bold chords}

\textbf{\chord{SI}}Gloria, manchi tu nell'\textbf{\chord{MI}}aria

\textbf{\chord{SI}}manchi ad una mano che lavora \textbf{\chord{MI}}piano

\end{song}
\end{document}
```

[image]