# Text with chords for guitar in Italian language

Tags: packages, hyphenation, music, songs

I would to write the words of a song (for example "*Immensamente*" of the singer-songwriter *Umberto Tozzi*) with a typewriter font, with manual hyphenation, but the top should adopt either a mathematical mode or write the text and chords on different lines or use some packages that I don't know.

I always hope that exists a **package** that can directly write the **chords over the text** including eventually the hyphenation.

I have seen this question/answer of the user **@Steven B. Segletes** [Two-lined text (text over text)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130865/two-lined-text-text-over-text)
that I have adapted with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

In \stackanchor{\small \textbf{DO}}{me}, immensamente in me\\
\stackanchor{\small \textbf{LA}}{La} notte si è appena spenta\\
E sono qui senza di te\\
Più te ne vai\\
E più ti sento\\
Più non ci sei\\

\end{document}
```

with this screeshot:

[image]

that it is not very similar to the this picture:

[image]

**My questions are**:

> 1. How to have the whole words aligned? For example "me" is not aligned

> 2. How to have a strong bold of **DO** (for example)?

Better fonts to use, or other alternatives code/packages, and a longer line spacing to optimally insert chords are welcome.
I hope my question isn't a bad one because I mentioned my favorite singer.

I have seen also an old link of an user [unique guitar tablatures from chords wrtten as \[*] in latex files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338295/unique-guitar-tablatures-from-chords-wrtten-as-in-latex-files) with an MWE taken from this link [songs package: how to store gtab definitions in an external file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151004/songs-package-how-to-store-gtab-definitions-in-an-external-file/151102), and that I add,

```
\begin{filecontents*}{tabs.txt}
A,X02220:001230
C#sus4,4:XX3341
Bb,X13331:012341
D,X00230:000123
E,022100:023100
F,133211:134211
    \end{filecontents*}

    \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage{xparse}
    \usepackage{songs}
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \ior_new:N \g_fedelibre_get_tabs_ior
    \prop_new:N \g_fedelibre_tabs_prop

    \cs_new_protected:Npn \fedelibre_add_to_prop:w #1,#2!!
     {
      \prop_gput:Nnn \g_fedelibre_tabs_prop {#1} {#2}
     }
    \ior_open:Nn \g_fedelibre_get_tabs_ior {tabs.txt} 
    \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_fedelibre_get_tabs_ior
     {
      \fedelibre_add_to_prop:w #1!!
     } 
    \DeclareDocumentCommand{ \fedetab }{ v }
     {
      \prop_get:NnNTF \g_fedelibre_tabs_prop {#1} \l_tmpa_tl
       {
        \fedelibre_gtab:nV {#1} \l_tmpa_tl
       }
       {
        \msg_term:n {Maybe~ you~ have~ mispelled~ your~ tab!}
       }
     }
    \cs_set_eq:NN \fedelibre_gtab:nn \gtab
    \cs_generate_variant:Nn \fedelibre_gtab:nn { nV }
    \ExplSyntaxOff


    \begin{document}
    \begin{songs}{}
    \beginsong{First Song}
    \beginverse
    \[A]Sed ut perspiciatis \[E]unde omnis iste \[Bb]natus error
    \[E] sit voluptatem \[A]accusantium doloremque \[Bb]laudantium
    \endverse
    \beginverse
    \[A]Quis autem vel eum iure \[E]reprehenderit qui \[Bb] in ea 
    \[E]voluptate velit esse \[A]quam nihil molestiae \[Bb]consequatur
    \endverse
    \endsong

    \beginsong{Second Song}
    \beginverse
    \[A]Sed ut perspiciatis \[D]unde omnis iste \[Bb]natus error
    \[E] sit voluptatem \[F]accusantium doloremque \[A]laudantium
    \endverse
    \beginverse
    \[D]Quis autem vel eum iure \[E]reprehenderit qui \[Bb] in ea 
    \[F]voluptate velit esse \[D]quam nihil molestiae \[Bb]consequatur
    \endverse
    \endsong

    \end{songs}
    % need code here to extract the list of all chords in the songbook
    % that contains more than 300 songs
    % with that list, I need the unique occurence of chords
    % then proceed to print each chord with \fedetab
    %for \fedetab info see this thread
    % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151004/songs-package-how-to-store-gtab-definitions-in-an-external-file/151102
    {\bfseries\Large Chords used in the Songbook A  Bb  D  E  F}
    \newline
    \newline
    \fedetab{A}  \fedetab{Bb} \fedetab{D} \fedetab{E} \fedetab{F}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe there is a package :) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522073/5049 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299284/5049

Comment: Wonderfullllllllllllllllllll.....Now I close my question like a duplicate. I have upvoted your package .

Comment: @cgnieder Do you know Umberto Tozzi?..."Gloria", "Ti amo"....

Comment: Ti amo is quite famous in Germany but I don't really know Umberto Tozzi, I'm afraid…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something just like your MWE, giving the fixed-do chord names in the argument to `\[]`, e.g.,

```
In \[DO]me, immensamente in \[SIbadd9]me...
```

etc. Is this not working for you?

Comment: ...with lot of humilty the output of the MWE is not very beautiful aesthetically..and I approve your answer with a positive vote.